# Remaining Amount: What's wrong with the code?

Tags: python, algorithm

Here is the problem statement for the Remaining Amount from Newton School. Swastik initially has rupees 1000 with him, he goes to a candy shop to buy some candies. There are only two types of candies available which cost 3 and 7 rupees. Swastik can buy any number of candies he wants, possibly 0, with the money he has.
Given the remaining amount of money he had left with him, your task to check whether the amount he has is possible or not.
Input
The first line of input contains the number of test cases T, next to T lines contains a single integer M(remaining amount).

**Constraints :-**
1 < = T < = 100
1 < = M < = 1000

**Output:-**
For each test case, in a new line print "Yes" if possible or "No" if not.

```
Sample Input:-
3
995
997
994

Sample Output:-
No
Yes
Yes
```

My code for this is:

```
cases = int(input())
for i in range(cases):
    target = int(input())
    val = 1000 - target
    if val % 3 == 0 or val % 7 == 0 or val % 10 == 0:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        diff = val % 7
        if diff % 3 == 0:
            print("Yes")
            break
        diff = val % 10
        if diff % 3 == 0 or diff % 7 == 0:
            print("Yes")
        else:
            print("No")
```

But only one test cases is passing. The site does not reveal those test cases which are giving Wrong Answer. Can anyone help me in this question?

Comment: Don't use modulo, but division. `5 % 3 == 2` but he still could buy 1 candy -> `5 / 3 == 1`. Or perhaps I haven't understood the statement

Comment: Write a trivial solution, no matter how inefficient, just needs to be correct. Use that to find values where your above solution fails.

Comment: @Cid Either he could buy candy for 3 or for 7 only not for 1.

Comment: You can buy for any amount greater or equal to 12. You can solve the other possibilities by hand and memorize the result.

Comment: @Damien Your approach works but how did you arrive at this logic?

Comment: As *7 - 2*3 = 1*, it is clear that you get a solution for all numbers large enough. You could also use that *7+3=10*. Then if it works for 12, 13, 14 ... it will work for 22, 23, 24... At the end, I simply made a few simple calculations to find that the highest not suitable number is 11.

Comment: @Damien That clears it out bro. Thanks for the help.